# How to get results of the weekend laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I’m trying to get results of the weekend in laravel. I would like to show all the events of the weekend during all the week. So I would like to show all results from monday to sunday, but just weekend events.
I have:

```
$friday = Carbon::parse('this friday')->toDateTimeString();
$sunday = Carbon::parse('this sunday')->toDateTimeString();
if (Carbon::now()->gt(Carbon::parse('this friday'))) {
        $friday = Carbon::parse('last friday')->toDateTimeString();
}
$events = Event::where([
        ['date', '>=', $friday],
        ['date', '<=', $sunday]
    ])
        ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

But when it’s satuday this doesn’t work. I don’t know how to do it. Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Just put in an `if` statement to check if "this friday" is in the future. If it is, use "last friday" instead.

Comment: What should it do on Saturday? should it show the events so far that weekend? or the events of the past full weekend?

Comment: I want to show the events of the weekend. Even if you're on Saturday or Sunday I want to show events on Friday, Saturday and Sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can use code:`$dt = Carbon::now(); $dt->isWeekend();` to check is weekend or not, then calculate the `$friday` date and `$sunday` date.

Comment: I'll try this: `if (Carbon::now()->isWeekend()) { $friday = Carbon::parse('last friday')->toDateTimeString(); }`, but I will have to wait until saturday to check if it works :)

Comment: oh! I didn't know! I changed the date and it works!. Thanks yusher!

Answer (score 0):

I also need to show events filtered by week and weekend:

```
$now = Carbon::now();


//This weekend's datarange
$starOftWeekend = $now->endOfWeek()->subDays(2)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$endOfWeekend   = $now->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');


//Weekly date range
$startOfWeek = $now->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i'); 
$endOfWeek = $now->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```